# change MYSQL insert query that uses SIZEOF to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, insert

I am changing over a website from mysql to pdo and want to  change a MYSQL insert query that uses SIZEOF to PDO This query works in mysql and i would like to change it to pdo. a form produces the input with item1, item2[] and item3[]. i have tried various insert array pdo examples but cant seem to get it right.

```
$item1 = $_POST['item1'];
$item2 = $_POST['item2'];
$item3= $_POST['item3'];

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($item2);$i++) {
    $qry4="INSERT INTO itemTable($item1,$item2,$item3) VALUES('$item1','".$item2[$i]."','".$item3[$i]."')";
    $result4=mysql_query($qry4);
    }
```

Comment: Include the PDO examples that you tried and that haven't worked.

Comment: prepare a statement before your for loop, execute it with the appropriate values in the loop. I would also check that $item3 has got the same (or higher) element count as $item2.